# Why do DAC circuits put the output through an opamp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, embedded, dac

In almost all the DACs found online, there will always be an inverting opamp connect to the output of the bias weight or R-2R circuit.

But in the [embedded courses in edx](https://users.ece.utexas.edu/%7Evalvano/Volume1/E-Book/C13_Interactives.htm#ITool13.3), there was no opamp and it still works OK when connected to an earphone jack.

So the questions are:

1. What does the opamp do in a DAC circuit, even though it has gain = 1?
2. Does inverting the signal somehow mess with the output sound?

Comment: The output impedance of an R-2R circuit is R. The output impedance of an R-2R-4R-... circuit is approximately R/2. In both cases, a buffer amplifier eliminates loading effects. If you don't care about loading effects, leave it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Adding a voltage buffer stops the loading effect and allows you to drive any load the buffer has enough current for. Without it the output of the resistor ladder will be loaded down with the input impedance of the next stage (your headphones) and will change the output voltage since the output impedance of the DAC is quite high (look up "input and output impedance of amplifiers").
   With headphones it probably doesn't matter very much.

This is also important if you're feeding the DAC through a reconstruction filter - A high output impedance will change the frequency response of an RC filter placed after it.

2. There is no audible difference between an audio signal and an inverted one. If you have multiple signals, you just need to make sure they are either all normal or all inverted. (section "Reversed Polarity with One Speaker" - https://audiouniversityonline.com/speaker-polarity)

If you have an inverting amplifier, make sure the bias is set correctly so that the output range is the same as the input range (e.g. 0-5V)

Answer (score 2):

1. There are different kind of DACs. Some have voltage output, some have current output. The output might be very weak and can not drive any substantial load. Since an op-amp takes virtually no current in, and can drive strong loads, the op-amp is used to buffer the weak DAC output to drive much stronger loads.
2. No, the inverting op-amp does not "mess the output sound". It just inverts it in the same way what happens if you reverse speaker positive and negative terminals. You can't hear the difference, as long as all speakers are connected with the same polarity.